# Custom Image Title scaling with Screen-width

Tags: java, android, customization, titlebar

Im trying to make a custom Titlebar for my App, which is no more, than an Image.

Totally custom example:
[image]

My Goal is to have the Size of the Picture scale by the Screen-width of the Display.

I already tried removing the TitleBar, and just placing an ImageView, but still a Titlebar, with App-Name and Icon got created...

Comment: Show how you tried removing the Title Bar.

Comment: I removed the `android:label` from the Activity from the Manifest

Comment: Also set "Not_Title" on graphical Layout.

Comment: Did you give my answer a try or is there something else that isn't right?

Answer (score 0):

Set this attribute in the `<application>` tag of your `manifest` to remove the Title Bar

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your activity like this in `manifest.xml`

```
   <activity
        android:name=".YourActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|keyboard" // this is hide keyboard
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" > // hide the title bar
    </activity>
```